Replication Error (SQL Server Management Studio 2019)
I am getting the following error in the Replication Monitor:
"The replication agent had encountered an exception. Source: Replication Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.NativeSqlConnectionException Exeption Message: Access is denied"
The replication script is working fine, but I can not find any more information in the logs about the cause of this error. As far as I know, it is not a permissions issue in the SQL Logs folder. Any idea what could be causing this?
I am using a vSphere VM.

based on this Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.NativeSqlConnectionException it should be an access to the target instance non to the folder.
please take a look at microsoft troubleshooting guide so you can better poit out what is going on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/troubleshoot-tran-repl-errors?view=sql-server-ver16

Thanks for the comment. After reading through that, the error is in the log reader agent. When viewing "Agents" in the replication monitor, it is giving an "Access denied" error message. Still not exactly sure what is causing it. I will try to enable verbose logging and see if I can get more info.
